# Dynamic query using Pl/SQL language

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, date-formatting

How can I get date format in `dd/mm/yyyy` using dynamic PL/SQL query..?

I have tried so many options but nothing works. Can anybody suggest correct way get date of birth in below format (`dd/mm/yyyy`)

```
V_DYNAMICSQL := 'select to_char(a.dat_of_birth) Date_of_birth
from genmst_customer a'

Execute immediate v_dynamicsql;
```

Comment: Why do you need the date as a string in a specific format? Do you want to write this to a file? Usually we just select the raw date and have the app that displays the date format it according to user's settings (e.g. Windows date settings). It is very rarey required to format a date with `TO_CHAR`. If you do want this, specify the format: `to_char(a.dat_of_birth, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. And why are you using dynamic SQL here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use dynamic SQL because there is nothing dynamic about your query. You can just select the value as a `DATE` (which has no format) and then when you want to **display** it, then you can use `TO_CHAR` and provide a format model:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_date_of_birth GENMST_CUSTOMER.DAT_OF_BIRTH%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT dat_of_birth
  INTO   v_date_of_birth
  FROM   genmst_customer
  WHERE  id = 1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_date_of_birth, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE genmst_customer (id, dat_of_birth) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1990-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 01/01/1970
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_UHabObJ)

Answer (score 0):

`to_char` itself isn't enough - you should provide **format model** as well.

Sample table:

```
SQL> desc genmst_customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 DAT_OF_BIRTH                                       DATE

SQL> select * from genmst_customer;

ENAME      DAT_OF_BI
---------- ---------
CLARK      09-JUN-81
KING       17-NOV-81
MILLER     23-JAN-82
```

PL/SQL procedure; note format model in line #5. I'm fetching only one row:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_dynamicsql varchar2(500);
  3    result       varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    v_dynamicsql := q'[select to_char(a.dat_of_birth, 'dd/mm/yyyy')]' ||
  6                     ' from genmst_customer a where rownum = 1';
  7    execute immediate v_dynamicsql into result;
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || result);
  9  end;
 10  /
Result = 09/06/1981

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**, based on your comment.

If you want to use alias and refcursor, no problem. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select name, to_char(dat_of_birth, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as dob
  7                from genmst_customer
  8                where rownum <= 3;
  9    return rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

NAME       DOB
---------- ----------
SMITH      17/12/1980
ALLEN      20/02/1981
WARD       22/02/1981


SQL>
```

Comment: What if I want use alias name of that column and display it using sysrefcursor

Comment: Nothing; use it, if you want. The result will still be in RESULT local variable, regardless of whether there is alias or not.

Comment: I edited my answer and added example which shows what you asked for. Have a look, please.